# How to put an entire SOAP envelope into a variable for batch XSL transformation

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt, soap, batch-processing

I need advice to process an XML document with bulk SOAP envelopes like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelopes>

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:sal="http://fc.com/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sal:divide>
         <arg0>3</arg0>
         <arg1>532</arg1>
      </sal:divide>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:sal="http://fc.com/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sal:divide>
         <arg0>3</arg0>
         <arg1>543</arg1>
      </sal:divide>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:sal="http://fc.com/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sal:divide>
         <arg0>3</arg0>
         <arg1>553</arg1>
      </sal:divide>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

</Envelopes>
```

I'm looking for a way to put the entire  in a variable for parsing.

Any ideas how to accomplish that using pure XSL transformation? ( with no Java code)

XSL fragment:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Envelopes/soapenv:Envelope">
   <xsl:message terminate="no" dp:priority="info">
       SomeUniqueString
   </xsl:message> 
   <xsl:variable name="fc" select="/Envelopes/soapenv:Envelope"/>
      <xsl:message terminate="no" dp:priority="info">
      <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
   </xsl:message>
   <xsl:message terminate="no" dp:priority="info">
      <xsl:value-of select="$fc"/>
   </xsl:message>
</xsl:for-each>
```

you can ignore the 'dp:' functions...

Comment: What do you mean by _variable_? In what context, in what language?

Comment: @MarcusRickert like in <xsl:value-of select="$whole-node"/>

Comment: Have you tried the normal variable declaration `<xsl:variable name="somename" select="soapenv:Envelope"/>`?

Comment: @MarcusRickert yes, it yields empty. I suspect anything tagged is escaped. Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: The contents of the select depend on the context within the XSLT sheet. Where do you call it? Could you include a stripped down XSLT?

Comment: Added at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

- The iterator `<xsl:for-each>` lets you access the current item using `.`. There's no need to use a select starting in the root node.
- For copying a node tree you need `<xsl:copy-of>` instead of `<xsl:value-of>` which flattens your output by just copying the text portions.

Try the following code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Envelopes/soapenv:Envelope">
   <xsl:message terminate="no" dp:priority="info">
       SomeUniqueString
   </xsl:message> 
   <!-- introduce a variable for the current envelope -->
   <xsl:variable name="fc" select="."/>
      <xsl:message terminate="no" dp:priority="info">
      <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
   </xsl:message>
   <xsl:message terminate="no" dp:priority="info">
      <!-- use copy-of the copy the whole envelope to the output -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="$fc"/>
   </xsl:message>
</xsl:for-each>
```